# cant restart sshd in boot2docker vm

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox, boot2docker, sshd

I installed boot2docker on a vm (host: windows 7)
My goal is to ssh into the boot2docker vm via putty.

I configured the /usr/local/etc/ssh/sshd_config file to my needs and now i wanted to reload/restart the sshd service.
I searched for the sshd file because "sudo service sshd restart" does not work. i found the following:
`/var/lib/sshd` `/etc/rc.d/sshd` and `/usr/local/sbin/sshd`
the first one says "Pemission denied", the second didnt print anything and the third says "not found"

Does anyone know how i can reload/restart the sshd service without rebooting?

Comment: What is the output of ``ps ax | grep sshd``?

Answer (score 1):

If you are ssh'ed into boot2docker, try `sudo pkill -HUP sshd`

```
Boot2Docker version 18.03.0-ce-rc4, build HEAD : c6a9f09
Docker version 18.03.0-ce-rc4, build fbedb97
docker@dockernode1:~$ sudo pkill -HUP sshd
docker@dockernode1:~$ Connection to 192.168.137.211 closed by remote host.
exit status 255

$ ./docker-machine ssh dockernode1
Boot2Docker version 18.03.0-ce-rc4, build HEAD : c6a9f09
Docker version 18.03.0-ce-rc4, build fbedb97
```

Make sure your `/usr/local/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is good, this boots you out of the server.

Correcting bad config is painful via HyperV Connect, doesnt accept Copy-Paste commands and Type Clipboard Text output gets corrupted. Have to type every character.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use services inside docker container (no systemctl, service). Everything has to run in foreground. You can use [supervisor](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) to run multiple apps inside one container. I would also recommend reading this response about [sshd inside docker](https://forums.docker.com/t/start-service-using-systemctl-inside-docker-conatiner/39992/2)

if you want to run sshd you have to run it in not daemonized mode using the `-D`

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

The path to sshd might be different in your container.